# ofstream- Writing an element into a file - C++

Tags: c++, c, file, ofstream

I want to write numbers into a file .dat in C++. I create a function, it uses ofstream. It's correct?

```
void writeValue(char* file, int value){
ofstream f;
f.open(file);
if (f.good()){
    f<<value;
}
f.close(); 
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try that? Did it work as you expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. It can also be simplified, for example:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void writeValue(const char* file, int value){
        ofstream f(file);
        if (f) 
            f<<value;
}

int main()
{
    string s = "text";
    writeValue(s.c_str(), 12);
}
```

It may be more convenient in C++, to take const char* rather then char *, because string can readily be converted to const char *.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but when i write a new number the old value is overwritten. unstead i want to write the new number in a new line. How can i do it?

Comment: Open file in append mode `ofstream f(file,ios::out|ios::app)` and add `endl` after writing each value: `f<<value<< endl;`

Comment: @Betelgeuse *"It doesn't work"* is not an error description. What's the expected behavior and what is the observed behavior? How did you observe the behavior?

Comment: I want to append new value into file.. but althought I open file in append mode, the previous value is overwritten.